# Добавление отключенного товара в корзину. Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Здравствуйте, как сделать чтобы отключенный товар также мог добавляться в корзину. Перекопал файл controller/checkout/cart.php и model/checkout/order.php но так и не понял где это мониторится.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь невидимый на сайте товар добавить в корзину?

Comment: Не обязательно делать его видимым чтобы добавить) Использовать ту же функцию cart.add(product_id)

Comment: В общем не для пользователей это)

Answer (score 0):

В файле `\system\library\cart\cart.php` заменить `p.status = '1'` на `p.status >= '0'`